# What does the RabbitMQ Connected Service in Visual Studio do?

Tags: rabbitmq, visual-studio-2022, connected-services

[image: rabbit mq container service dependencies in visual studio]

I noticed that Visual Studio has a connected service for RabbitMQ containers.

However the documentation currently only states:

> RabbitMQ on container
>
> RabbitMQ is an open-source multi-protocol message broker. This option
> makes it available in a local container.

Which doesn't really describe it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/overview-connected-services?view=vs-2022#support-for-azure-emulators-and-local-alternatives

The subsequent link only details Azure Functions ability to leverage RabbitMQ:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-rabbitmq

I was hoping it might provisions the container via docker desktop (you can right click and view containers), but it does not.

It only seems to provision connection strings in user secrets / nuget packages, but little else. Am I missing something in it's feature set? I'm unable to find any further docs.